# Importing bulk CSV data in UTF-8 into MySQL

Tags: mysql, utf-8, csv, load-data-infile

I'm trying to import about 10K rows of UTF-8 encoded data into a new MySQL table.

I can do so successfully with `LOAD DATA INFILE` via MySQL Workbench but it the UTF-8 characters get mangled. I've tested the database otherwise via PHP and it accepts stores UTF-8 charaters fine. The problem seems to be with `LOAD DATA INFILE`, and I've come across a few threads about this.

Does anyone know a workaround, or possibly another similarly easy method to import CSV data?

Thank you.

**RESOLVED:**

For others who see this and have the same problem, just add character set as a parameter when running `LOAD DATA INFILE`. Simpler than I realised :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to [MySQL documentation for LOAD DATA](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html), you can specify a `CHARACTER SET` parameter in your statement to provide the input file character set.

Have you tried providing `'utf8'` as the input character set?