# UTF8 from Database does not display correctly (Codeigniter)

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, utf-8, collation

i have a webserver setup consisting of Codeigniter, Mysql and Apache.

One a page load i fetch data from a mysql table which looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `names_table` (
`id` integer NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
....
`name` varchar(180) NOT NULL,
....
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;
```

The data on the serverside is displayed with

```
echo $this->db->get_where('names_table', array('id' => '6'))->result()->name;
```

The header of the page served to the client is sent via

```
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8");
```

plus i am setting the meta information to

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

The PHP file serving the client request is encoded in UTF-8 without BOM, but the name is displayed like **SchÃ¶nefeld** although is should be **Schönefeld**.

The name field with the corresponding id in `names_table` has *536368c383c2b66e6566656c64* stored in it.

I spent a few hours searching for possible solutions and i already applied all hints i found so far without working. Thank you very much.

---

EDIT:

Before displaying the data to the client i run

```
mb_detect_encoding($name_field);
```

which says it is UTF-8. I am viewing the page in Chrome where UTF-8 encoding is set, too.

If i understand it correctly, i should not call `utf8_decode()` on the variable returned from the database because the browser already understands that the document is in UTF8 and takes appropriate action to decode it, correct?

**RESOLVED**

As it turns out the data in the table was not imported correctly. I had to use an explicit statement about the character set for it, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2133198/importing-bulk-csv-data-in-utf-8-into-mysql)

Comment: Have you set the connection encoding to `utf8` in the CI database configuration? I'm not a CI guy, so can't tell you where exactly that is, but that's your problem...

Comment: Yes, i have set the character set to utf8 and the database collation to utf8_bin.

Comment: In the *Codeigniter database connection configuration file*, right?

Comment: Well, maybe http://kunststube.net/frontback can give some more inspiration...

Answer (score 1):

Set the connection to UTF-8.

MySQL:

```
SET NAMES utf8;
```

With mysql:

```
mysql_set_charset('utf8', $connection);
```

With mysqli:

```
$connection->set_charset('utf8');
```

Etc.

Comment: I put this statement before every query to the database for testing. It does not work.

Comment: You do not put it before every query. You put it once right after creating the connection.

Comment: P.S. Also make sure that the character set is not set to something different in your server, because it WILL override your html meta tags. In Apache there's a directive for this: AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

Comment: I have enabled the default charset as UTF-8 in apache.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your file has been saved as **UTF-8 without BOM**.

It depends what IDE you use but for example in Notepad++ There is a Encoding File Menu.